# Using MVP and Databinding to bind an onclick method from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvp

I have an activity and a fragment. I'm using the MVP pattern. I am trying to bind through databinding the onClick method for abutton in that fragment, to no avail.

I have tried:
A) setting the name for the presenter as presenter which is the name of the presenter in the fragment.
B)fragmentPresenter which is the name of the presenter in the activity.

The respective code snippets:

Activity

```
    private HomeFragmentPresenter homeFragmentPresenter;
    private HomeFragment homeFragment;
```

Fragment presenter

```
    @Override
    public void handleBookTitleEditButtonPress(View view) {
        System.out.println("Pressed edit button");
        DataRepository.ChangeCurrentBookName(newTitle);
    }
```

fragment xml

```
 <data>
        <variable
            name="homeFragmentPresenter"
            type="se.hkr.fictioner.data_fragments.home_fragment.HomeFragmentPresenter" />
    </data>
   
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/current_book_title_edit"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_black_24dp"
                android:onClick="@{homeFragmentPresenter::handleBookTitleEditButtonPress}"
                android:contentDescription="TODO" />
```

Is there a way to do it in this fashion? Thing is I have 2 buttons and I want to bind a field from the presenter to an editText.text

Answer (score 0):

Ok the error was that I forgot to add the actual binding to the onCreateView() for the fragment. Here is a sample from a different fragment that uses the same scheme.

Old

```
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                                 ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState){
            View view = inflater.inflate(inflater, 
                                            R.layout.character_fragment,container,false);
            recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.character_recycler_view);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            return view;
        }
```

New

```
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                                 ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState){
            CharacterFragmentBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, 
                                            R.layout.character_fragment,container,false);
            View view = binding.getRoot();
            binding.setPresenter(presenter);
            recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.character_recycler_view);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            return view;
        }
```

Let this be here for posperity.